# Processing with Threadpool and executor service

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have an ArrayList of 10 elements. I initiate a threadpool of size 10 and call execute with an element passed into each thread. Each thread does some processing with that element as input and outputs the result. The problem is, the output sometimes has processing results of only 7 elements sometimes and 8 sometimes with a few duplicates and 9 sometimes. I am not sure why I do not have the processing results of exactly 10 elements. Here's my code snippet.

```
ExecutorService exeSvc = 
                Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)
for (Object element: arlList)//arlList is the arraylist of 
                                                           size-10
{
   exeSvc.execute({->myRunnable element});
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the output , if it's possible?

Comment: If a thread finished a job ,it instanly takes a next one, so sometimes the first threads take 2 jobs before the last threads create .That 's why you have duplicates.

Comment: "*`exeSvc.execute({->myRunnable element});`*" - This will not compile.

Comment: Try something like this   `for (Object element: arlList) {
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread();
            executor.execute(worker);
          }
        executor.shutdown();`

Comment: 1. why it's tagged as `groovy`? 2. inside `for` declare local variable as copy of your `element` variable and use the copy within `execute({})`. 3. use   `execSvc.shutdown() && awaitTermination()` to wait all executions finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

groovy...

```groovy
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

ExecutorService exeSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)
for (int element=0;element<9;element++) {
    int elementCopy = element
    exeSvc.execute({->
        Thread.sleep(567); 
        println "${Thread.currentThread()}  element = $element elementCopy = $elementCopy"; 
    });
}
println "All Started"
exeSvc.shutdown()
exeSvc.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
println "All Finished"
```

outputs

```
All Started
Thread[pool-12-thread-1,5,main]  element = 9 elementCopy = 0
Thread[pool-12-thread-2,5,main]  element = 9 elementCopy = 1
Thread[pool-12-thread-3,5,main]  element = 9 elementCopy = 2
Thread[pool-12-thread-4,5,main]  element = 9 elementCopy = 3
Thread[pool-12-thread-5,5,main]  element = 9 elementCopy = 4
Thread[pool-12-thread-1,5,main]  element = 9 elementCopy = 5
Thread[pool-12-thread-2,5,main]  element = 9 elementCopy = 6
Thread[pool-12-thread-3,5,main]  element = 9 elementCopy = 7
Thread[pool-12-thread-4,5,main]  element = 9 elementCopy = 8
All Finished
```

as you can see in my case the `for` loop finished before threads started and all of them has `element` value 9 and `elementCopy` is different

Comment: Thank you! This indeed solved my problem. All I had to do was copy the element to a local variable inside the for loop. Great!!!

Answer (score 0):

That's because `main thread` finishes erlier than `ExecutorService`.

To force `Main thread` to wait for `ExecutorService` to finish processing, use this:

```
exeSvc.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //this will 5 second to finish all tasks
exeSvc.shutdown();
```

Comment: This assumes that the threads in the pool are daemon threads.

Answer (score -1):

Execution time for each element is not the same. So, at the end of process, shutting down thread is required. You can use,

```
if ( check_whether_operation_is_done ) {
    Logger.info( "Process shutdown" );
    exeSvc.shutdownNow();
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  Also, you should call `shutdown()` (not `shutdownNow()`) after the last job is submitted to the pool.